# Error while adding Paging in Dynamic grid?

Tags: ext.net

I have created a Dynamic grid but while trying to add paging toolbar I am getting "Runtime error- "undefined is null or not an object".

//ascx Code

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" ClassName="Defatult3UserContorl" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Collections.Generic" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Ext.Net" Namespace="Ext.Net" TagPrefix="ext" %>

<script runat="server">
    private DataTable GetDataTable()
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        table.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] {
            new DataColumn("Company")   { ColumnName = "Company",    DataType = typeof(string) },
            new DataColumn("Price")     { ColumnName = "Price",      DataType = typeof(double) },
            new DataColumn("Change")    { ColumnName = "Change",     DataType = typeof(double) },
            new DataColumn("PctChange") { ColumnName = "PctChange",  DataType = typeof(double) },
            new DataColumn("PctChange") { ColumnName = "LastChange", DataType = typeof(DateTime) }
        });

        foreach (object[] obj in this.Data)
        {
            table.Rows.Add(obj);
        }

        return table;
    }
    private object[] Data
    {
        get
        {
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

            return new object[]
            {
                new object[] { "3m Co", 71.72, 0.02, 0.03, now },
                new object[] { "Alcoa Inc", 29.01, 0.42, 1.47, now },
                new object[] { "Altria Group Inc", 83.81, 0.28, 0.34, now },
                new object[] { "American Express Company", 52.55, 0.01, 0.02, now },
                new object[] { "American International Group, Inc.", 64.13, 0.31, 0.49, now },
                new object[] { "AT&T Inc.", 31.61, -0.48, -1.54, now },
                new object[] { "Boeing Co.", 75.43, 0.53, 0.71, now },
                new object[] { "Caterpillar Inc.", 67.27, 0.92, 1.39, now },
                new object[] { "Citigroup, Inc.", 49.37, 0.02, 0.04, now },
                new object[] { "E.I. du Pont de Nemours and Company", 40.48, 0.51, 1.28, now },
                new object[] { "Exxon Mobil Corp", 68.1, -0.43, -0.64, now },
                new object[] { "General Electric Company", 34.14, -0.08, -0.23, now },
                new object[] { "General Motors Corporation", 30.27, 1.09, 3.74, now },
                new object[] { "Hewlett-Packard Co.", 36.53, -0.03, -0.08, now },
                new object[] { "Honeywell Intl Inc", 38.77, 0.05, 0.13, now },
                new object[] { "Intel Corporation", 19.88, 0.31, 1.58, now },
                new object[] { "International Business Machines", 81.41, 0.44, 0.54, now },
                new object[] { "Johnson & Johnson", 64.72, 0.06, 0.09, now },
                new object[] { "JP Morgan & Chase & Co", 45.73, 0.07, 0.15, now },
                new object[] { "McDonald\"s Corporation", 36.76, 0.86, 2.40, now },
                new object[] { "Merck & Co., Inc.", 40.96, 0.41, 1.01, now },
                new object[] { "Microsoft Corporation", 25.84, 0.14, 0.54, now },
                new object[] { "Pfizer Inc", 27.96, 0.4, 1.45, now },
                new object[] { "The Coca-Cola Company", 45.07, 0.26, 0.58, now },
                new object[] { "The Home Depot, Inc.", 34.64, 0.35, 1.02, now },
                new object[] { "The Procter & Gamble Company", 61.91, 0.01, 0.02, now },
                new object[] { "United Technologies Corporation", 63.26, 0.55, 0.88, now },
                new object[] { "Verizon Communications", 35.57, 0.39, 1.11, now },
                new object[] { "Wal-Mart Stores, Inc.", 45.45, 0.73, 1.63, now }
            };
        }
    }
    private GridPanel createDynamicGrid()
    {
        Store store1 = new Store();
        GridPanel grid = new GridPanel();
        Ext.Net.Model model = new Model();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            ModelField modelField = new ModelField();
            if (i == 0)
                modelField.Name = "Company";
            else
                modelField.Name = "Price";

            model.Fields.Add(modelField);

        }

        store1.Model.Add(model);
        store1.DataSource = this.GetDataTable();
        grid.Store.Add(store1);
        grid.SelectionModel.Add(new RowSelectionModel { Mode = SelectionMode.Single });
        grid.ColumnModel.Columns.Add(new ColumnBase[] { 
            new Column 
            {
                Text = "Company",
                DataIndex = "Company",
                Flex = 1
            },
            new Column
            {
                Text = "Price",
                DataIndex = "Price"

            }
        });
PagingToolbar pagging=new PagingToolbar();
    grid.BottomBar.Add(pagging);

        return grid;
    }

    protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, DirectEventArgs e)
    {
        createDynamicGrid().Render(this.frmGrid, RenderMode.AddTo);
    }
</script>

<ext:FormPanel ID="frmPanel1" runat="server">
    <Items>
        <ext:Button runat="server" ID="btnSearch" Text="Search" Icon="FeedMagnify" X="150"
            Y="10">
            <DirectEvents>
                <Click OnEvent="btnSearch_Click" />
            </DirectEvents>
        </ext:Button>
        <ext:FormPanel ID="frmGrid" runat="server">
            <Items>
            </Items>
        </ext:FormPanel>
    </Items>
</ext:FormPanel>
```

//Aspx Page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Ext.Net" Namespace="Ext.Net" TagPrefix="ext" %>
<%@ Register TagName="Table" TagPrefix="uc" Src="~/MiscExamples/Defatult3UserContorl.ascx" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Ext.NET Examples</title>

    <script runat="server">

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <ext:ResourceManager ID="ResourceManager1" runat="server" />
    <ext:FormPanel ID="frmPanel1" runat="server">
        <Content>
            <uc:Table runat="server" ID="SearchTable" title="Search Table" />
        </Content>
    </ext:FormPanel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In this above example I have one user contorl where I am creating GridPanel dynamically.
And in Grid panel I want to do paging with 10 record in a page.
But while trying to add pagingToolbar
        "PagingToolbar pagging=new PagingToolbar();
         grid.BottomBar.Add(pagging);"
it's throwing me runtime error.
can you please help me out. Appriciated your help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add the following settings:

```
Store store1 = new Store();
store1.ID = "Store1";
store1.PageSize = 10;
```